# React JS Animated accordion - built using details and summary

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm currently building a custom accordion in React using `<details />` and `<summary />`
Here's what I have so far - [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-platform-4h8tp)

As you can see in the codesandbox, a weird problem is happening. Every time I click on one of the accordions, only the last item's content shows up. I can't figure out what's causing the weird issue.

A snippet of my handle click function, for a full code please refer to the sandbox link above:

```
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const accordion = summaryRef.current.parentNode;
    const content = contentRef.current;

    if (accordion.hasAttribute("open")) {
      content.style.removeProperty("max-height");
      content.classList.add("closed");
      setTimeout(() => {
        accordion.removeAttribute("open");
      }, 400);
      return;
    }
    // If the <details> element is closed, add the [open] attribute (so the content will render), and animate in
    accordion.setAttribute("open", "");
    // Get proper max-height for element for better animation
    if (!content.getAttribute("data-height")) {
      content.style.maxHeight = "none";
      content.setAttribute(
        "data-height",
        `${content.getBoundingClientRect().height}px`
      );
      content.style.removeProperty("max-height");
    }
    // Wait for the browser to apply [open] to <details>, then animate
    setTimeout(() => {
      content.classList.remove("closed");
      content.style.maxHeight = content.getAttribute("data-height");
    }, 0);
  };
```

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: That's because your `summaryRef` object is set to the last item in the `map`. You iterate over `data1` and `data2` array but repeatedly assign the `summary` element to `summaryRef`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you re-reference `summaryRef` and `contentRef` in a `for` loop. Because that the actual value of refs will be last item. I advice to make items as a separate components and keep refs under them.